# Initiating a segue from uiview or uivewcontroller that is not on storyboard

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard, segue

How can I initiate segue from a custom `UIView` or custom `UIViewController` that is not on Storyboard? - they are created programmatically inside a parent `UIViewController`.
Although the destination `UIViewController` is on the storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Then just do it the old fashioned way. Instantiate it and present it modally or just push it if you are in a navigation controller. Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

You can talk about segue only if it is in the storyboard. If Your source View Controller is not in it, you just present the next one as I said. You can instantiate your destination view controller from the storyboard:

```
MyViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

From this point you will be "back in the storyboard" so you can perform segues in the destination View Controller.

Comment: Thanks.  That is what I did.  But unfortunately, my storyboard does not capture all the flow:(

Comment: What do you mean by "capture all the flow"?

Comment: I mean - flow from one controller to the other.  Programmatically pushing or presenting modally is not represented in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

First give storyboard id. Select the view controller than write a identifier(Storyboard ID)
[image]

Secondly, just open your .m file then write belove codes.

```
UIStoryboard * st = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"nameOfStoryboard" bundle:nil];
MyViewController *viewController = [st instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourStoryboardID"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Last line of code. Might also be

```
[self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```